# Rpart and Tidymodels Integration

Tags: r, tidymodels, rpart

I am trying to replicate a code I have using the `rpart` package to adjust a poisson decision tree, to use it with `tidymodels`.

Code Using `rpart`:

```
features <- c('is_renewed', 'gender', 'age_group', 'cluster_k3', 'insured_amount')

dt_freq <- rpart(
  formula = as.formula(paste('cbind(exposure, n_claims) ~', paste(features, collapse = ' + '))),
  data    = dat_train,
  method  = "poisson",
  control = list(minsplit = 16, maxdepth = 3, cp = 0.00025))
```

Code Using `Tidymodels`:

```
dt_spec <-
  decision_tree(
    cost_complexity = 0.00025,
    tree_depth = 3,
    min_n = 16) |>
  set_engine("rpart", method = "poisson") |>
  set_mode("regression")

fit_dt <-
  parsnip::fit.model_spec(
    object = dt_spec,
    formula = as.formula(paste('cbind(exposure, n_claims) ~', paste(features, collapse = ' + '))),
    data    = dat_train)
```

With both codes I obtain the same fit of the decision tree and it generates exactly the expected results. However, the values of the hyperparameters were previously found. Now, trying to replicate the tuning process with `tidymodels`, I get errors with respect to the formula specification.

Code Using `Tidymodels` for Tune Decision Tree:

```
tree_spec <- decision_tree(
  cost_complexity = tune(),
  tree_depth = tune(),
  min_n = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("rpart", method = "poisson") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

tree_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(tree_spec) %>%
  add_formula(as.formula(paste('cbind(exposure, n_claims) ~', paste(features, collapse = ' + '))))

tree_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(x = extract_parameter_set_dials(x = tree_spec), size = 50)

doParallel::registerDoParallel()

set.seed(345)
tree_rs <-
  tree_wf %>%
  tune_grid(
  resamples = folds,
  grid = tree_grid,
  metrics = metric_set(yardstick::rmse)
)
```

Errors:
Warning message:
All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more information.

"Error in str2lang(x): :1:32: unexpected symbol\n1: cbind(cbind(exposure, n_claims).exposure\n                                   ^"

[image]

Comment: The tidymodels framework does not currently support that kind of `cbind()` syntax for the outcome. There is [an issue open here](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/266) about supporting this feature, and I suggest that you add some more details about how you'd like to use it.

Comment: Hi Julia, thank you for answering my question. As you indicate in your issue what I want is to model a ratio. In this case, I have the count of claims that each individual has declared to an insured and the exposure of the time that individual has been at risk for the insured, this generates a ratio known in actuarial science as the usage rate or frequency of use. It is common to use generalized linear models with a poisson adjustment to model this variable, using the offset term to make it a ratio.

Comment: I understand you say that `tidymodels` does not support that syntax but why when I use parsnip::fit.model_spec I get the expected result?

Comment: I believe because in that case, the formula is just passed straight through to the underlying modeling function. When you tune or use other parts of the tidymodels infrastructure, the outcomes and predictors are parsed and handled more separately.

Comment: Do you recommend I create my own parsnip model?
https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/

Comment: I don't believe that will solve the problem, unfortunately; it's a limitation of the rest of the tidymodels infrastructure currently (like tune, mainly).